# Specific permissions for Github apps to read internal type repo?

Tags: github, github-app

I am using Github apps as a PAT for mirroring my repos but for private and public type it able to read and mirror it but when it comes to internal type its not at all reading those repos.

how can i proceed ? any way for specific permissions required i cannot see any such thing even on documents also